# Restoring Windows 8/8.1 file history in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, restore, file-history

Is it possible without doing any manual work (i.e. manually copying file history-saved files and de-duplicating and renaming them) to restore a Windows 8 backup (produced by File History) in Windows 7 or on Mac, for that matter)? Is there a tool?

Thanks!